# Vue-cli 3 Environment Variables all undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, environment-variables, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I've tried all of the solutions out there but none seem to work for me. I just want to store some values in a `.env` file within my Vue app but simply trying to log `process.env` returns an empty object from within the component.

My `.env` file

```
VUE_APP_URL={api url}
VUE_APP_TOKEN={token}
```

My plan was to set these environment variables to data properties but it always returns `undefined`. If I do `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` from webpack.config.js it will show that I'm in development but if I tried doing the same from within the component like

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_URL);
    })
  }
```

It just returns `undefined`.

Comment: Where you have copied the .env file? You should place it in the root directory as sibling to 'package.json'
And hope u r accessing the values like this 
proceess.env.VUE_APP_URL

Comment: My `.env` file is in the root directory and is a sibling to package.json and webpack.config.js. Calling `process.env.VUE_APP_URL` from a component returns `undefined`

Comment: As some answers and comments, here and on [this github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1610) state, you might just need to restart the server. Some comment states that they had to run `npm run build` and `npm run dev` to make it work. There might be some cache or something similar (I'm not sure of that)  

But I am sure that hot reloading won't take into account any changes to .env files

Comment: Just to note, that .env files are publicly contained in the and should not contain private data, like eg. an API token.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured it out - I had to install `dotenv-webpack` and initialize it in webpack.config.js which is odd because none of the docs stated that I needed to do so.

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking for a solution for several hours now. It's so strange as host and port was overwritten in config/index.js with a simple ```require('dotenv').config();```. I would never have guessed that I would need anything extra to use the variables in Vue components.

Comment: If someone is as stupid as I am, I missed the fact that the files should start with .env (for example, only the file name .env). Instead, I used the myconfig.env file, which was wrong. So in my vue app builded with cli 3.x it works without any dotenv.config or something like that

Comment: I have searched a lot, but this is the only solution I tried which works with webpack without vue-cli. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 151):

A few tips for people who land here:

1. Make sure your `.env` files are **in the project root folder** (and not in say `src/`)
2. **Variable names should start with** `VUE_APP_` if to be statically embedded into the client bundle
3. **Restart** the dev server or build your project for changes to take effect
4. If you are migrating from a webpack based solution make sure that you replace `:` (from JSON config) with `=` (**dotenv format**). Easy to miss
5. Make sure you've saved any changes to your `.env` files.
6. In old Vue versions environment variables were defined in e.g. `config/dev.env.js` instead of the `.env` files in root

Comment: Even with HMR, this didn't work until I reloaded the server :/

Comment: Yes, HMR will not help with environment variables. The project needs to be rebuilt for changes to take effect.

Comment: Also save the .env files. Every time you change them. And then restart again.

Comment: Another tip: Coming from Python I am conditioned to manually loading the .env file. It took me an embarrassingly long amount of time to realize that you do not need to explicitly load it anywhere. Just put it in the root folder, follow this answer's instructions, and let the magic work itself.

Comment: in my case it was the missing `VUE_APP_` prefix, thx

Comment: in my case, I've spent the whole day trying everything but I had my .env files in uppercase and that caused them to stop working after building the app in a pipeline

Comment: It was the missing `VUE_APP_` prefix. So we can't use variables without this prefix in the `.env` file?

Comment: GOD! Why did no one tell me the variable names should start with `VUE_APP_` before? This thing drove me crazy this morning! THANKS!

Comment: IT works! Thank You. I had to SAVE (i forgot) the .env file : ) and i had to stop and close de browser. I restart the server, open the browser, and it works!

Comment: point 3 (restart server) fixed mine! Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Vue with Laravel Mix then replace ```VUE_APP_``` with ```MIX_APP_```.

Comment: Restarting the server `npm run serve` worked for me

Comment: HOLY MISSING `VUE_APP_` PREFIX BATMAN!
Literally wasted a day on this.  Thank you for this post, it saved me unknown amounts of further head-banging.

Answer (score 19):

Install `dotenv-webpack` and configure the `vue.config.js` file as follows.

```sh
npm install dotenv-webpack --save-dev
```

Add this to your config file:

```js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');


module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv()
    ]
  }
}
```

In your `.env` file make sure you add `VUE_APP_` before your variables like this:

```
VUE_APP_VAR1=example
VUE_APP_VAR2=value
```

Now you can access these variables in your Vue application:

```js
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_VAR1); // "example"
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_VAR2); // "value"
```

Here some links for reference:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack
- https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html
- https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Comment: This does not work for me. The config file causes a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')`.

Comment: This worked for me thank you, I'm using  Vue 3 without vite - February 2024

Answer (score 13):

so I use 
VUE_APP_API_URL (this doesn't work)
then I change it to
VUE_APP_APIURL (this works)

hope it helps

Answer (score 9):

If your **vue-cli** *version* is higher than **3.x** and you put your .env files in root directory like said in comments. Than you can access your environmental variables from components (like this `process.env.VUE_APP_YOUR_VARIABLE`).
As said in [vue-cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code)

> Only variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the client bundle with `webpack.DefinePlugin`. You can access
>   them in your application code: `console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET)`

Answer (score 7):

I know that this question was asked about `vue-cli` 3, which generates code for Vue 2. But it is the top result if you google for "vue3 does not embed env" and similar queries, so I assume that a lot of people end up here when having trouble with `process.env` variables being undefined in their Vue 3 app.

So this is an answer about how to fix your Vue 3 env issues.

**This is what causes the confusion**

1. If you google for env problems with vue, you end up in the [`vue-cli` docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html). But `vue-cli` was replaced by `create-vue` in Vue 3. There is a alert box at the top of the page that tells you this, but you've probably missed it.
2. If you did not miss it and followed one of the two links in the box, you ended up in the Vue 3 tooling guide or in the `create-vue` repo. None of those resources mention env variables. But you learn that `create-vue` is based on Vite.
3. If you follow that lead and google for "vite env", you end up in the [`vite` documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html), where you finally find the answer:

   - env variables have to be prefixed with `VITE_` to be compiled into the app (as opposed to `VUE_APP_` in `vue 2`)
   - env variables will be available in `import.meta.env` in your app (as opposed to `process.env` in `vue 2`)

The latter one is what took me the longest to figure out.

**This is how you need to do it**

in an `.env` file in your project root:

```bash
VITE_MY_ENV_VAR=foo
```

The docs will also tell you about the different naming patterns for .env files in Vite. Very useful information if you work with different environments!

in your app:

```
const my_env_var = import.meta.env.VITE_MY_ENV_VAR
```

I hope this saves someone the time for figuring this out.

Comment: Good lord, I can't believe it took me so much searching to get this explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I put my .env file in the root directory and appended each variable with `VUE_APP_`.

To demonstrate this, for example, if the variable you want to use is `API_BASE_URL`

In your `.env` file, you put the variable as `VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL=baseurl/api/v1`

To access it in your files, you do `process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL`.

## CAVEAT:

Never put any sensitive information you don't want anybody to see, on your front-end. The most common thing you won't want anybody to see (as regards web development) is your API Key. There are real consequences to doing this. [This](https://medium.com/@morgannegagne/a-very-expensive-aws-mistake-56a3334ed9ad) is one such example of someone who has been burned exposing API keys to the public.

However, even if you put your sensitive data in a `.env` file and add the `.env` file to a `.gitignore` file (hence not pushing it to a Git repository hosting service e.g Github, BitBucket, Gitlab etc.), your data is still not safe on the front-end. It's only safe when this is done on back-end code as it will be hosted on a server.

In the front-end, anyone who is determined enough can find your sensitive information. All your information is available on a browser and all that person needs to do is to open the `dev tools` and check the `Sources` tab, and BOOM all your sensitive information is laid bare.

Environment variables on the front-end are only useful when you want one reference point for NON-SENSITIVE information, such as a BASE URL, as seen in the example above. A BASE URL can change during the course of development and you won't want to change all references in the application folder manually. It is tedious plus you may miss a few, which would lead to errors.

If you want to avoid exposing your API keys and other sensitive information you may require on the front-end, take a look at this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/private-api-keys/).

Answer (score 3):

IF you are using VITE, use VITE_ in stead of VUE_APP

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me. I previously created my .env.development and .env.production files in the root folder by manually by right-clicking in the Exploer in VS Code and adding a new file. This kept giving me undefined.

I deleted the files and first installed `npm install touch-cli -g`
Once installed, i added the environment files as such `touch .env.production` and `touch .env.production`and itworks. So I think there's a difference between how these env files are generated.

NOTE: I do not have webpack installed. Just using the vue cli to build

[VS Code Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZZLu.png)[Chrome Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAAhy.png)

Comment: this is weird..  it works for me as well.. but than I deleted the files created via `touch` and recreated using vs-code file creation UI... and it worked then...  :D

Answer (score 2):

Vue CLI `dotenv` usage suffers the inability to provide the `.env` variables other than prefixed with `VUE_APP_`. This is OK but this is far not enough to satisfy any even little serious web project that wants to conveniently and securely manage its (sometimes huge) list of variables for different environments.

Here is the solution that makes use of `.env` variables as convenient as on backends with `dotenv`.

With this solution you could access your `MY_EXTERNAL_API_KEY` from your `.env[.environment]` file in your code like this `const key = process.env.MY_EXTERNAL_API_KEY`.

It provides:

1. The convenience of using non-prefixed with `VUE_APP_` variables' names and use `.env` variable [expansion feature](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv-expand) (use `${VARNAME}` kind of variables)
2. The necessary security: your variables are neither available at browser console with `console.log(pocess.env.MYVAR)` at run time nor are explorable via text search by their names from `.env` files within the built application's JS bundle.
3. You can still use [original Vue CLI solution](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) along;

For this use `dotenv-webpack` plugin in your `vue.config.js` as follows:

```js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const envPath = function() {
    return (!process.env.NODE_ENV || (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')) ?
        './.env' :
        `./.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`;
}

const dotenvArgs = {
    expand: true,
    path: envPath()
};

module.exports = {
   //... some other config here
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new Dotenv(dotenvArgs)
        ]
    }
};
```

Here:

- `expand: true` allows for `${MYVAR}` variables expansion;
- `path: envPath()` allows to define custom `.env` file name [depending on your Vue CLI project environments](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes-and-environment-variables), and the path depending on you project structure;

There are other useful `dotenv-webpack` [options](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack#properties) you could use.

I believe this solution is good enough to fully satisfy most frequent use cases.

NB: Remember as you pass your secret variables set via `.env` into HTTP requests from your front-end (e.g. an API key in a call to some external API) they are visible to any one who knows where to look. To diminish security risks for this situation there are different solutions.

Just to hint you have either to:

- provide only publicly open data via your application;
- or authenticate your application (or parts of it) via some authentication service (login/password + JWT|sessions, external authentication providers e.g. Facebook, Google etc.);
- or resort to server-generated application.

But this is the whole separate subject.

Answer (score 1):

if you are cominng from VUE-cli-2 or you just cloned/installed an old vuejs project and you can't find `.env` file, this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-working-with-environment-variables#step-2-%E2%80%94-using-env-files-with-vue-cli-2) explains what you have to do to set your `.env` variables as they environment files are probably located in `config/dev.env.js` (Note: this is peculiar to Vue-cli-2 files)

Here is also a solution and a detailed [explanation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-working-with-environment-variables#step-1-%E2%80%94-using-env-files-with-vue-cli-3) for Vue-cli-3 .env related issue

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was changing from `.env` to `.env.local`. Haven't investigated WHY but I checked an old project and saw that I had a `.env.local` instead and did same for this project that would not pick the values from `.env` irrespective of whether vars where prefixed with `VUE_APP` and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me together with the `VUE_APP_` prefix in the variables' names. I also noticed that it will add the prefix in the name if you just name it something like `FOO`. In that case, it's accessible as `VUE_APP_FOO`. I'm not sure what I have to do the `.local` either. The [official doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) mentioned that `.env` is loaded in all modes. Maybe I understood it wrong?

Comment: I lied about the auto add prefix thing. Just a misbehavior of mine during testing... Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

It seems environment variables are not accessible in child Vue components. Best to declare them globally in `main.js` with `Vue.prototype.env = process.env;`

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I was calling the file as "**variables**.env.development", but the right way is just "**.env.development**", with the dot starting the name. I removed the "variables" part and everything worked fine.

- Inside the ".env.development" file: `VITE_TEST=123f`
- In any file: `console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_TEST);`

Answer (score 0):

It might also help: make sure your .env files are in lowercase letters because in Linux it won't work even if it is working in windows

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/loading-env-var-using-process-env-undefined/44187/3) helped me out. I'm using Laravel with an odd setup for Vue 2.x. The project is also using Laravel Mix. Here's the solution:

Inside of your .env file, which is a sibling of package.json:

```
MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=my_value
```

Inside of webpack.mix.js:

```js
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin (
                ['MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE']
            )
        ]
    };
});
```

Afterwards, an `npm run dev` or `npx mix` should allow you to use these variables.

Credit: [Thorsten Lünborg](https://github.com/LinusBorg)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the `env` variable like this:

```
import.meta.env.VITE_APP_MDP_API_URL
```

Reference:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

your variable files
.env
.env.production
must be in root of project
not in src Folder

```
VUE_APP_API_URL = http://localhost:7326/api/

const NODE_ENV = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL;
console.log(NODE_ENV);
```