# VUE/CLI .env variables returns undefined

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli-4

I'm using @vue/cli 4.2.3 but when I create a .env file in my project root folder and declared a new env variable in it then print it in any component it returns undefined.
My env variable is like
`VUE_APP_NAME=VALUE`
and I'm calling it like
`console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_NAME)`
and the result is always undefined
Any help, pls?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue-cli 3 Environment Variables all undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510326/vue-cli-3-environment-variables-all-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

With the information you give it seems that you are doing well.

1. The file is in the root.
2. The variable starts by `VUE_APP_`

I would check that the .env file has no extension.

Comment: It's a normal .env file is there anything more I can do?

Comment: Supposedly not, but if you have disabled the file extension view you may have created a .txt.

It is a supposition, I already tell you, by the data you put you are doing well

Comment: Thanks for your time I'll keep searching.