# Library dotenv-webpack doesn't work with vue 3 and webpack-cli

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, dotenv, webpack-cli

I'm using Vue 3 and Webpack 5 and wanted to install dotenv-webpack, but I can't get it to work.

Here's full code: https://github.com/golebiewska-n/webpack5-vue3

Setup: `package.json` script I'm using to launch the app

```
webpack-cli serve
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
...
module.exports = (env) => {
  return {
    ...
    plugins: [
       ...
       new Dotenv()
    ]
  }
}
```

`.env` (added in the root folder of my app)

```
VUE_APP_VAR=123
```

`main.js`:

```
console.log(process.env)
```

and output in console is:

> MISSING_ENV_VAR

I tried removing `new webpack.DefinePlugin({...})` from plugins in webpack config, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you successfully loaded the `.env` file with `dotenv-webpack` and the `VUE_APP_VAR` is accessible. It is just you cannot use the entire `process.env` object as `dotenv-webpack` does not allow it showing you `MISSING_ENV_VAR` instead.

If you chnange line 12 in your `src\Layout.vue` as follows:

```js
- return process.env
+ return process.env.VUE_APP_VAR
```

you get your `123` value of the variable in your Vue app.

The reason is at the time of building your application with webpack `dotenv-webpack` replaces the explicit string `process.env.SOME_EXPLICIT_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE` existing in your code with the actual value of `SOME_EXPLICIT_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE` if that exist in the Webpack JS environment's actual `process.env` object.

This means you never get the entire `process.env` object accessible in your webpack bundle, and the bundle does not comprise the variable names like `VUE_APP_VAR=123`. This is the goal of `dotenv-webpack`.

You can get some more details in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529648/6597265).

PS: `DefinePlugin`, being returned in the build config, could override `process.env`. It does so in Vue CLI (which is hardly justifiable). So its effect there sould be neutralized manually for `dotenv-webpack` to work within Vue CLI (v4 and v5) applications as expected.

Comment: Since process.env returned "MISSING_ENV_VAR" I didn't even try returning process.env.VUE_APP_VAR, because it didn't make any sense to me. Thank you so much for your explanation!

Comment: Yeah, it is all sometimes gets tricky. Welcome :)